# Libgdx project not working when I shift to other computer

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have a libgdx project with me, and it was working quite perfectly in my computer, but when I installed intellij on the other computer and imported it, it doesn't work.

**When I import using Gradle:**

It doesn't even take it as a project!

---

**When I import using Eclipse:**

It no longer has all of the libs like libgdx.

Ex:

```
ShapeRenderer sr; // Shape Renderer in red.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks/

Comment: Did you checked whether the .iml file is being deleted. because if so the intelij will not detect it as an intelij project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something goes wrong with projects depends on IDE, you can do simple thing - just create empty LibGdx project with installer and put in it you src folders and assets. After that try to import in second computer.

If that has no effect, you can try download another IDE - Android Studio last versions for example.